# What does "clearance fee" mean?

Tags: single-word-requests

Here's the content:

> What is Stock Music?
>   Stock Music, also commonly known as Production Music, is a less expensive alternative to the use of popular or well known music in a production, since it is not necessary to obtain specific permission or pay additional **clearance fees** for the use of a song that has instant recognition.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it would appear to be a fee charged by a company involved in ensuring royalties (/in general, other duties etc) of the correct amount are paid to owners of copyright (/customs etc) for their work.

Comment: Clearance Fee:  the fee you pay in order to have the music cleared for use in your production.

Comment: Edwin Ashworth, thank you!
GEdgar thank you,
I haven't known there's a meaning "approve" in the word "clear" until you explained to me.

Comment: @HKK See this definition: [clear](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/clear) _verb_ (GIVE PERMISSION): **to give official permission for something**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to Obtain Sample **Clearance** for Use in One's Music](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/how-obtain-sample-clearance-29725.html)

> If you plan to use music of other artists' work, you may need to get
>   permission (**clearance**) and pay a **fee** in order to avoid legal trouble.